# Convert Netezza table DDLs into Snowflake version

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, netezza

I have Netezza DB table DDL's in bulk for which I would like to convert them into Snowflake version. Is there any simpler method to do this?

Please advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you DDLs are ANSI SQL standard, then it will work without any issue as Snowflake SQL is [ANSI SQL (1999 & 2004)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying.html) standard and hence it makes the SQL migration easy. What part of SQL makes so different in Netezza which you think is not compatible with Snowflake SQL?

Comment: Distribute ON/ Random, Organize ON, Explicit type conversion like NVHARCHAR... These are few items which are not supported in Snowflake